# AWS DeviceFarm: How to access test.parameters passed to "ScheduleRun" API

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-device-farm

Does anyone know how to access the `test.parameters` key-value pairs passed as input to the [ScheduleRun](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/API_ScheduleRun.html#API_ScheduleRun_RequestSyntax) API?

This is what I am doing:

1. Passing the input for the test to be run under `test.filter`.
2. Passing the parameters I need for my test under `test.parameters`. I have ensured it is a valid JSON object.
3. I am not passing any `yaml` file, so a "standard" test run gets triggered on DeviceFarm.

Here is my code that I use to retrieve the data:

```
final Bundle bundle = InstrumentationRegistry.getArguments();
for (final String key : bundle.keySet())
{
    final Object obj = bundle.get(key);
    Log.i(TAG, "Key - '" + key + "' ; Value - '" + obj.toString() + "'");
}
```

I know the `test.filter` part works because the `InstrumentationRegistry.getArguments()` bundle is able to retrieve the `class` value which is the test that needs to be run. Unfortunately, the `test.parameters` values are not present in the bundle.

Is there anything that I am missing or should I use some other mechanism to retrieve the `test.parameters` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got confirmation from the AWS team that, at this point, they don't support this feature for Custom environments.